# Using the dot "." character in MVC4 Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently serving images from a database tables which are all of the same file type. I would like the character dot "." in the routes, but have not had any success doing so. It is my understanding that the ISAPI handlers could be causing an issue related to this. I'm just unsure how I would go about adding and exclusion to allow just this route to be handled by ASP.NET.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ImageUrl",
    url: "Image/{action}/{id}.png",
    defaults: new { controller = "Image" }
);
```

Comment: I think `/image/find/2.png` may give you the `Resource not found` exception

Comment: I am using the Azure Websites which leads me to believe it is either 8.0 or 8.5. @Murali the precise problem I'm trying to fix is that 404 error as a result of the ISAPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 404 errors because there is no specific managed handler mapped to path `*.png` in IIS configuration. So all requests to `Image/*.png` paths are intercepted by `StaticFile` modules (`StaticFileModule, DefaultDocumentModule, DirectoryListingModule`) and these modules can not find requested files.

You can workaround this problem by configuring your application in `web.config`.

*The first option* is to add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` attribute to `configuration/system.webServer/modules` element. It should be looking like this:

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

**NOTE:** But I would strongly recommend to not doing this. Read more about [possible performance problems](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html).

So *the second (and much better) option* is to register ASP.NET ISAPI for handling your requests to `Image/*.png` path:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ImageMVCHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="image/*.png" verb="GET,HEAD" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ImageMVCHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="image/*.png" verb="GET,HEAD" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ImageMVCHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="image/*.png" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you the second option is precisely the example I was looking for as I haven't had any experience regarding handler configuration.